# I get a 401 error status when I run my Elasticsearch python script

Tags: authentication, elasticsearch, python-requests

I am writing a python script where I need to use my Elasticsearch credentials to delete all indices that have a doc.count 0.

I have created a test user which has been granted privilege to delete_index to all indices beginning with the name "test".

Here is part of the code to help:

```
ELASTIC_SEARCH_USER = _secret_client.get_secret("Elastic--User").value
ELASTIC_SEARCH_PASSWORD = _secret_client.get_secret("Elastic--Password").value
ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL = _secret_client.get_secret("Elastic--URL").value

elastic_auth_uri = f"https://{ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL}/security/_authenticate"
response = requests.get(elastic_auth_uri, auth=(ELASTIC_SEARCH_USER, ELASTIC_SEARCH_PASSWORD), verify=False)
              
# Defining a params dict for the paramaters to be sent to the API
search_url_ending = "_cat/indices/test*"
url_ending_deletion = "_cat/indices"

params_dict = {
"h":"index,docs.count",
"s":"docs.count:asc",
"format":"json"
}

# Elastic authentication to list the indices
elastic_console = f"https://{ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL}/{search_url_ending}"
print(elastic_console)
getRequestElasticSearch = requests.get(elastic_console, auth=(ELASTIC_SEARCH_USER, ELASTIC_SEARCH_PASSWORD), verify=False, params=params_dict)
content = json.loads(getRequestElasticSearch.text)

# Elastic url required to index deletion
elastic_console_delete = f"https://{ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL}/"
elasticsearch_url = requests.get(elastic_console_delete, auth=(ELASTIC_SEARCH_USER, ELASTIC_SEARCH_PASSWORD), verify=False)
print(elasticsearch_url.url)


# List indices with doc.count 0
for index in content:
    indiciesList = index
    collectdoccount = index['docs.count']
    search_int = int(collectdoccount)
    if search_int == 0:
       print(index['index'] , index['docs.count'])
       index_name = index['index']
       delete_url = f"{elastic_console_delete}{index_name}"
       response = requests.delete(delete_url)
       if  response.status_code == 200:
           print(index['index'] , index['docs.count'])
       if  response.status_code != 200:
           print (index['index'] , "index not deleted")
           print(response.content)
```

I can list the indices, but deleting them comes with 401 status errors.

The error is:

> b'{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"action [indices:admin/delete] requires authentication","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":["Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\"","Bearer realm=\"security\"","ApiKey"]}}],"type":"security_exception","reason":"action [indices:admin/delete] requires authentication","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":["Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\"","Bearer realm=\"security\"","ApiKey"]}},"status":401}'

I don't understand fully what this error means. Based on what I've read on Google, I have not provided sufficient authentication credentials to complete this deletion request.

Can anyone help me with my dilemma please?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Elasticsearch has security enabled and the error message `action [indices:admin/delete] requires authentication` states that you need to provide username password for that request.

You just need to use `auth` param for the delete request just like you did with `get` previously.

```
requests.delete(delete_url, auth=(ELASTIC_SEARCH_USER, ELASTIC_SEARCH_PASSWORD))
```